# Eevee rendering 2.82, Viewport is fine. Final render has white transparent gloss or film over entire image. Cycles works fine

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

Cycles render [image: Cycles Render]

Eevee render [image: Eevee Render]

1.)The Cycles render is a cropped image of some shelves, the books on the shelves, two converging walls and the world backround above.

2.)The Eevee render is a cropped image of the end of those same shelves, the wall, and the world backround through a open window.

If at all informative. Eevee renders the image without the white glossy overlay until finished,as if only when the render is fully complete does the white film appear over the otherwise normal render. 
Thank you for reading.

Comment: Have you checked your Renderlayer settings? It's possible that you use a pass that eevee doesn't create.

Answer (score 0):

These are the passes I had enabled, I turned them off and on in multiple combinations and also tried a render for single layer. No luck I am afraid.

[image: Render layer settings]

I realize I posted this in answers rather than comments. I am new please excuse this mistake.

Update:

I have found something that has seemingly fixed the issue for a picture render. After the render has completed If I set the following dropdown menus from left the right as the following values,
1) slot one
2) view layer
3) combined 
4) color and alpha

Then I can save my image as intended. I can only hope this temporary fix will also work for an animation. I cannot be certain until I render it. 
I still am curious as to if this is a proper and permanent fix. I fear it is not.

[image: Render window settings]

Final update:

I have fixed my issue. Combined with what is above turning off both compositing and sequencer in post processing worked.

[image]

There may be some unnecessary changes, as in what is in my first update. Or perhaps compositing is the problem and sequencer is not and vice versa. 
I will not know until I test more, but I am done with this thread. 
Thank you to the poster who set me on the right track. 
Thanks for reading.

Comment: The same above settings do not fix the original problem for an animation. This is troubling.